# Handling large numbers with vpa in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to sum each digit in the number 2^1000, for instance, the sum of each digits in 25346 = 2+5+3+4+6 = 20.

I wrote a code in Matlab looking like this:

```
clc, clear all, close all,
x=2^1000;
x=vpa(x,400);
sum=0;
while x>0 
    num=mod(x,10);
    sum = sum+num;
    x=floor(x/10); 
end
sum % = 1349, correct answer should be 1366
```

For smaller numbers, this code works. I'm guessing there's something fishy with the vpa command, but I can't figure out what.

Anyone have any ideas? Is there an easier and faster way of doing this in matlab?

Answer (score 1):

Merge these two lines as it is shown in the documentation:

```
x=2^1000;
x=vpa(x,400);
```

to this

```
x=vpa(2^1000,400);
```

Comment: This gave me the same results.

Comment: @Phiger What about vpa(sym(2)^1000)?

Comment: That gave the same result.

Comment: @Phiger Did you take a look at this question? https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/59178-sum-digits-of-big-numbers